# Selenium using chromeDriver and ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to start my node Selenium-IDE ruby test/unit export in Chrome on Windows.

I have found all kinds of solutions that "should" work, however I can't even get a instance of Chrome launched!

Solutions that I've tried (but did not succeed of course):

```
@driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:9515", DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
@driver = new Chromedriver();
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
      :remote,
      :url => "http://192.168.1.30:4444/wd/hub",
      :desired_capabilities => caps)
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

I've run my selenium server with the `Dwebdriver` included and have a `nodeConfig` that makes 5 instances of chrome available.

I hope I've given enough information, if not please ask! I really can't figure out how to fix this on my own any more :)

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: 1) Error:
file_name(test_name):
NoMethodError: undefined method `ChromeDriver' for #<test_name:0x2dd45b0>

  file_name.rb:11:in `setup'

While using this as setup:
<code>
def setup
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
    @driver = new ChromeDriver(
      :remote,
      :url => "http://192.168.1.30:4444/wd/hub",
      :desired_capabilities => caps)
    @base_url = "https://somewebsite.com"
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end
</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PATH is where the system will look for the `chromedriver.exe` file. If the `.exe` isn't in your PATH the system won't find it.

You can find details of the file locations on your computer which are included in your PATH by right clicking My Computer and going to `Properties -> advanced -> environment variables` and find the `PATH` in the selection box. You can edit it to add a new location or put the .exe in an existing location.

I have it in C:\Ruby187\bin, I may have had to add this manually when first setting up ruby but I can't remember :o)